# Hash element reference inside puppet manifest

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to complete one of the first exercises, which is including the `hostname` and `osname` facts in the `/etc/motd`. I simply cannot get this to work properly. I cannot get an element out of a hash.

I'm using the VM at puppet, and the copy and paste isn't working for me so I'll use screenshots.

[image]

So I create my `motd.pp`:

[image]

But after running `puppet apply motd.pp`, I see this:

[image]

I've tried:

```
$os[name]
$os['name']
${os}[name]
${os}['name']
$facts['os']['name']
$::os['name']
$::os[name]
```

Pretty much every permutation I could think of and it always ignores the `[name]` or `[os][name]` part of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing this. There is the Puppet 4/Facter 3 way which is:

```
file { '/etc/motd':
  ensure  => file,
  owner   => 'root',
  group   => 'root',
  content => "${facts['networking']['fqdn']} OS name is ${facts['os']['name']}\n",
}
```

and the Puppet 3/Facter 2 way which is:

```
file { '/etc/motd':
  ensure  => file,
  owner   => 'root',
  group   => 'root',
  content => "$::fqdn OS name is ${::os['name']}\n",
}
```

You can also do this with Puppet 4 and Facter 2. It would work with the syntax from the first example but the fact location in the second example.

```
file { '/etc/motd':
  ensure  => file,
  owner   => 'root',
  group   => 'root',
  content => "${facts['fqdn']} OS name is ${facts['os']['name']}\n",
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, worth linking to the docs which explains the two different methods: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_facts_and_builtin_vars.html#the-factsfactname-hash

Comment: @MattSchuchard, the OP claims to have tried the Puppet 3 / Facter 2 approach you suggest to him, with the same result -- just as I would expect.

Comment: Yes this post is what I already tried and I had already read the docs, perhaps I missed a part about extending the curly braces all the way around. Thank you John Bolinger for your answer which I upvoted.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Right, I kept forgetting about hash lookups needing the curly brackets when interpolated inside a string. Remembered it for a while but then hadn't done it in a while so forgot again. Updating for that.

Answer (score 2):

To *interpolate a value from a hash into a string*, you need to enclose the whole expression after the `$` inside curly braces.  Optionally, you can use the same form for ordinary variable references (and in some case you must do so to avoid the variable's name being misinterpreted):

```
file { '/etc/motd':
  ensure  => file,
  owner   => 'root',
  group   => 'root',
  content => "${::fqdn} OS name is ${::os['name']}\n",
}
```

The presence or absence of single quotes around the hash key is immaterial, but I recommend the quoted form as better style.

Without the curly braces, Puppet does not recognize the subscripting operator inside the string as going with the variable, so it interpolates the string value of the whole hash, and appends the subscript as plain text.

Comment: This works very similarly in perl but for some reason I didn't think of that because I'm new to this DSL.

Comment: I just spent some time googling for the documentation about the special treatment hash lookups require when interpolated, and I could find nothing. This answer seems to be the closest thing to documentation about it. I only first learned of it from a support ticket response from one of the junior developers almost a year ago which completely agreed with the assertion in the first sentence, thus proving it as factual.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, FWIW, the [v4 docs on string interpolation](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.8/reference/lang_data_string.html#interpolation) seem to cover this.  They specify that the curly-braced form is the *standard* form.  The braces can be omitted only in the special case that you want to interpolate the whole value of a variable, and some words are devoted to making all that precise.  The [v3.8 docs](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/reference/lang_datatypes.html#double-quoted-strings) say pretty much the same thing, but not as clearly.